# Searching for a Calendar Application That Meets the Following Criteria

Tags: calendar

My Step Father is starting his own company, and he gets the wonderful life of having to deal with multiple clients.

He needs a calendar system that can do the following:

- Can be updated from iCal (I'm pretty sure this just means CalDAV support)
- Needs to be able to show different clients the details of whats on his calendar for them, while showing other client's arranged times as only busy
- Wants to show it in a professional way, preferably on his own website.

I was looking at Google Calendar, but alas it doesn't seem to actually support it like I thought it would.  He was looking at MobileMe, but its simply public.

Is there a calendar app or PHP application that can be installed on his server that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you set up Google Calendar via Google Apps for Domain (which is free for up to 50 users I think) then you don't have to "invite", you can just add the calendars of other people in your domain.

Answer (score 0):

Google Calendar seems to be your best choice. What doesn't it support?

Comment: In order to use Google Calendar for this, each 'client' would have to be invited to EVERY SINGLE ONE of the client calendars, each of them as busy/available only except for their own, unless you know something I don't?

Comment: I am still a bit confused by what you need. Do you want each person to have their own personalized calendar?